# Function parameter that accepts functions with some or no parameters

Tags: android, kotlin, parameters

I want to be able to pass **both fun1 and fun2** to the parameter myAction of the class MyAdapter **without adding a MyClass? parameter to fun2**. The function fun2 doesn't use the parameter myClass, so if I add it, I would have a parameter that's not used.

Is there a way to do this? when searching for a method, I found about vararg but it doesn't seem to work in this scenario.

```
class MyAdapter(
    var myAction: (myClass: MyClass?) -> Unit
)

fun fun1(myClass: MyClass?) {
    Log.d("fun selected")
    myClass.print()
}

fun fun2() {
    Log.d("fun selected")
}

fun initAdapter(){
    val adapter1 = MyAdapter(::fun1);
    val adapter2 = MyAdapter(::fun2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could always just pass a proxy function to `MyAdapter` which calls `fun2`. So something like this:

```
MyAdapter { fun2() }
```